# Using WebAudio API from NodeJs

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, web-audio-api, webkitaudiocontext, audiocontext

I want to use WebAudio(AudioContext) in NodeJS. However NodeJS does not support WebAudio. There is an npm for web-audio-api but it is still in alpha stage and is incomplete.

So how can I use WebAudio(AudioContext) in NodeJS.

Can I instantiate a chrome browser environment from NodeJS and utilize its capabilties. Is this possible?
Is there any other way to do it?

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use node-webkit or app.js to use WebAudio API and talk with it with socket.io.