# Manipulating audio (in PHP ? Another language ?)

Tags: php, audio

I would like to start a voice synthesizer project, first just by cutting and pasting or joining pieces of sounds recorded previously as .mp3 or similar with a microphone, that once treated would then be saved as .mp3 or similar, to probably then be displayed in a browser.

But the problem is I don't see any information about PHP which could do it.
Do you have any ressource with this programming language for audio-related projects ?

Is it easier to manipulate audio with another programming language ?

Thank you.

Comment: If you want to run this in the browser, maybe JavaScript is the way to go. Check out: [Waveform Playlist on github](https://github.com/naomiaro/waveform-playlist), a "*Multitrack Web Audio editor and player with canvas waveform preview.*".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should consider using something like Node js for this. It has plenty of packages and sure something for audio. I just googled and found this:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/web-audio-api

Comment: I also found this SO questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25197708/using-webaudio-api-from-nodejs

Comment: Hmm, thank you, but this is not really precise. Do you have a precise ressource or a part of code ?

Comment: I cant programm the software itself to you but if i just google Node js synth I found this : https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodesynth
I think you should just consider reading something about node js its great! Use it on your local machine with the git bash so you can use a linux console on your windows system. Follow other tutorials etc and I think you will get what you want.

Comment: Otherwise look at the Links provided in this SO Question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21996275/audio-manipulation-using-node-js

Comment: So if it was helpful it would nice if you can mark my post as answer. :)

Comment: I prefer to gather as many results as possible for the moment.