# trim and concat audio files in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, audio, ffmpeg

I want to trim and concat several audio files in Node.js. I found `FFmpeg` and it looks like it does what I need, but I don't know how to use it in Node since the installation is through `apt-get`. Theoretically, I can use what's called `child_process` to execute several commands from bash, but I'm not sure if this is performant.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Audio manipulation using node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21996275/audio-manipulation-using-node-js)

Comment: Not exactly. That thread is 4 years old and has 2 answers while in JS you get new framework every week :P

Answer (score 7):

Of course you can do this by spawning a *child_process* and use *ffmpeg* this way. This should perfectly works without any noticeable performance problem.

However there is a *[fluent-ffmpeg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fluent-ffmpeg)* package that you could use for more convenience.
For example you can trim a file with the `-t duration` option and concat files with `-f concat` option. You can also use the builtin method `mergeToFile()`.

Example:

```
// trim file
ffmpeg('input.wav')
  .inputOptions('-t 2') // 2s
  .output('output.wav')
  .run()

// merge file
ffmpeg('input.wav')
  .input('input2.wav')
  .mergeToFile('merged.wav')
```